# Is there a way to define timer precision / reduce output, when using Dropwizard Metrics?

Tags: java, dropwizard

Dropwizard Metrics provides a lot of seemingly useful log outputs for the timers, but much of it I am not going to use now, and it simply clutters my log files (I am using the `Slf4jReporter`). Also, due to the high accuracy levels of the averages and ratios, it is difficult to read through the log files at a glance.

Is there a way to:
- drop the accuracy to say 2-4 digits after the floating point?
- filter out the less immediately relevant stuff like percentiles, stdev, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe the easiest would be to create your own implementation based on the `Slf4jReporter`. You can either copy the class and modify what you need or extend it and override the methods you need for achieving what you are looking for.

Comment: @hveiga that's a way, yes. Maybe, I will try that.